# Override just the vertical scroll bar portion of a ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, scrollbar

Is there a way to get at the vertical scroll bar portion of a ComboBox in C#?  I'm writing an app that's going to run on a touchscreen, and I want to widen the vertical scroll bar part of a ComboBox.  Is there a way to get at that component of a ComboBox, or am I just out of luck on this?  I'm using WinForms.

Comment: What are you using? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: If its winforms, you'd need to owner draw the combobox.

Comment: Should have been clearer.  This is WinForms.

Comment: Are you willing to write a custom windows forms control? It will take more work, but may in the long run be beneficial. I don't know that comboboxes have any properties allowing you to change the scrollbar width, so either way it will likely take some manipulation

Comment: I would certainly love to learn how to write my own custom controls, but I'm relatively new to C#, and I have no idea where to begin writing such a complicated control.  I was hoping that there was some simpler way to widen the scroll bar in .net control.

Comment: Through Control Panel -> Display -> Appearance -> Advanced, any user can set the Size of the Scroll bar system-wide.  I would imagine most touch-enabled PCs to already have this increased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the scrollbar width on just one control.  The width is a system setting, SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth property in Winforms.

The fix is to recognize that this isn't just a problem for a combobox, any scrollbar will be hard to use on a touch screen.  So change the system setting.  On Windows 7, use Control Panel + Display, Personalization, Window Color, Advanced appearance settings.  Item = Scrollbar, increase the size.  You'll also want to increase the Caption Buttons size so the close button gets easier to hit.  Etcetera.

[image]

Note that the comment about the Basic theme is nonsense.

Comment: Can't do that in my particular case (don't have access), but that would work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer provided by @Hans Passant applies to Windows 7 only and is no longer available in Windows 10, you can actually use the tool that I published on my GitHub in the following link:

https://github.com/codewondo/Windows-Scrollbar-Width-Changer

This tool changes the scrollbar by modifying the registry.